# Как открыть последний открытый активити?

Tags: android

Как открыть последний открытый активити? Я из MainActivity перехожу SecondActivity, по нажатию в домой сворачивается приложения и при нажатие обратно открывается SecondActivity, а при сворачивание(не убиваю приложения) и по нажатию значку приложения открывается    MainActivity. почему так происходит? должно же открывать? как решить данную проблему?

Comment: Переформулируйте. В данный момент вы утверждаете, что одно и то же действие у вас имеет разный результат.

Comment: Такое поведение проявляется только при первом запуске после установки? Т.е. если убить приложеньку и запустить заново это воспроизводится?

Comment: решил данную проблему в манифесте удалил android:launch="singleTask"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

удалил в манифесте `android:launch="singleTask"`